# New line in string with Date

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have date in DateTime format, and I convert it to String

```
myModel.myDateToString("dddd, d MMM 'hour.' HH:mm", myCulture);
```

Now date in string is in one line. I want to make it like:

```
Monday, 7 mar
hour. 10:00
```

Is it possible ? Or I  must to separate it to two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a new line char in the format string, it worked for me

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(
             string.Format("dddd, d MMM {0}'hour.' HH:mm", System.Environment.NewLine)
             , culture);
```

Comment: The political correct way to do it: use Environment.Newline

Comment: To clean this up, you can also now use string interpolation such as DateTime.Now.ToString($"dddd, d MM{Environment.Newline}HH: mm")